# Failed to execute child process “-bash”: Failed to execve: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

What is the problem about Terminal? Anyone help?

[image: Terminal Image]

Comment: It looks like there is a typo somewhere in your shortcut to start the terminal..

Answer (score 3):

The problem about the terminal is that it fails creating a child process it is told to create. For example, exactly the same symptoms are seen when executing

```
gnome-terminal -- -bash
```

This instructs to start Gnome Terminal and run the command `-bash`. Such command does not exist, so the terminal fails with exactly the same appearance as your are showing.

Thus, investigate how you start the terminal. The error is there, in the command line used to start the terminal.

Comment: For gnome terminal, It gives me this error. Path issue?

`bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` indeed is where python3 normally is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration of the `gnome-terminal` by executing the following command in the "Run a Command" dialog. The dialog can be access with the short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

[image]

Then check the if there is a custom command specified in the user profile section.

[image]

It should point to the default location of the `bash`: `/usr/bin/bash`